# Uncaught TypeError with use of select menu in simpledialog2 of jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, simpledialog

Is Simpledialog2 not supported select menu in jQuery Mobile ?

Because when I use select menu in Simpledialog2, I get error like as under,
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery1910010748725151643157' of undefined"

And if I do not use select menu than it's working fine, how strange it is.

I am trying without select menu as under, It's working fine.

```html
<div id="inlinecontent" style="display:none;">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <label>My Label</label>
          <input value="myval" type="text">My Value</input>
        </fieldset>
        <a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'> Close </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now I am trying with select menu, I get Uncaught Type Error in console and it's not working :(

```html
<div id="inlinecontent" style="display:none;">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <select>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'> Close </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js code as under,

```js
    $(self.el).find('#inlinecontent').simpledialog2({
        mode: 'blank',
        headerText: 'My header text',
        headerClose: true,
        blankContentAdopt: true,
        blankContent : true
    });
```

Can any one help me to fix this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can show your JS code of jQM and SD2?

Comment: I have edited it in question.

Comment: I render html pages (developed to based on jQM) in Backbone Views with use of underscore.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible dont use **`Simpledialog2`** with **`jQuery Mobile`**. Last version was made to work with **`jQuery Mobile 1.0.1`**. That was a long time ago and a jQuery Mobile has changed a lot since then.

You should use jQuery Mobile native **[dialog](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/dialog/)** or native **[popup](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/popup/)** instead. You will get same functionality and unlike Simpledialog2 these are not 3rd party plugins.

One of possible reasons why this is not working because **`jQuery Mobile`** don't support 2 popups at the same time. When select is opened its will show a popup (unless it is turned off, but default state is popup select) and because **`Simpledialog2`** is already a popup it will throw an error.